# Possible to fetch data from remote folder on IIS server?

Tags: android, iis-7, file-storage

So far I have worked with remote Linux servers where I fetched data via PHP layer. Is it possible to do the same with a remote storage server that runs IIS 7.5 server?

I basically need to list files of a remote folder and fetch specific file(s) from an Android application.

If I can do this, should I create a C# layer with JSON output (like I do with a PHP layer) or there is another (better) way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used IIS since 1997, but it looks like you can run PHP on it nowdays? You might be lucky and can reuse your PHP layer.

You can find more info at: http://php.iis.net/

Comment: Well yes if this was my server. It is a provider who offers remote storage. You think they'll be cooperative or I should just look for the service on a Linux server?

Comment: They might already have php support. Have you checked their documentation? Many hosting companies add the most common requirements to their servers... but I would look for a company with linux.